# HTML characters on DocuSign XML Resource File

Tags: docusignapi

Trying to customize DocuSign pages using resource files. Tried to modify the XML downloaded file and upload it again.

All the texto modifications are OK, but HTML escaped chars that previously were correctly rendered now are escaped in the HTML.

By example:

```
<data name="ActivationSec_SMSAuthDesc">Para acessar seu contrato, confirme seu número de telefone cadastrado:&gt;br&lt;;&lt;ol class="MOB_orderedList" &gt;&lt;li&gt;Clique em "Enviar SMS" para receber sei código de confirmação.&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Insira o código recebido na próxima página.&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ol&gt;</data>
```

This text should render a list (and it did, with the original text), but it doesn't:

[image]

How should I edit the XML resource file to accomplish that? Looks like a bug to me.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issues and couldn't find any answers on the DocuSign support docs.

The solution is annoyingly simple. Just use plain HTML tags! When you upload the resource file these tags are automatically converted.

```
<data name="ActivationSec_SMSAuthDesc"><b>Bold Text</b><br />New Line</data>
```

This example is using XHTML tags and works fine. Not sure about HTML5 support.